# SQLの正規表現で文字列中の<a>タグを全削除したい

Tags: mysql, sql, 正規表現

下記は wp_posts テーブルの post_content カラム (type = LONGTEXT) のデータです。

**対象データ:**

```html
<h1 id="title1">h1</h2>


<a href="#title1">aaa</a>
<a href="#title2">bbb</a>
<a href="#title3">ccc</a>
<a href="#title4">ddd</a>
<a href="#title5">eee</a>

<h2 id="title2">h2</h2>
```

`href="#title"` となっている `<a>` タグを全削除したいです。削除後に下記のようになっているのが理想です。

**削除後:**

```html
<h1 id="title1">h1</h2>

<h2 id="title2">h2</h2>
```

このようなSQLになると思うのですが、これに `href="#title"` となっている `<a>` タグという条件を加えたいです。
MySQL 5.6を使っています。

```sql
UPDATE
  wp_posts
SET
  post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<a href="#title1">aaa</a>', '') WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%<a href="#title1">aaa</a>%';
```

Answer (score 1):

title の部分が任意の文字列という前提であれば、

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<a href="#.*?">.*?</a>', '')
```

という感じでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！<a></a>の間にあるtitle は仮で入れたものでして、本当は色々な文字列が入るのですがそういった場合はどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: @Take 任意の場合は `.` を使えばいいかと。回答を修正しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！あと１点質問させてください。```REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<a href="#.*?">.*?</a>', '')``` の後にwhere句は必要ないんでしょうか？

Comment: @Take もしかして WordPress ですか？ `REGEXP_REPLACE` は MySQL 8.0 以上で使えます。

Comment: 古い MySQL では正規表現を使った置換は難しいと思います。mysqldump でデータベースをエクスポートして、sed などでファイルを処理してから、インポートして戻すという力技が[本家](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9456574/3501958)で紹介されていました。

Comment: ワードプレスです！MySQL 5.6だと、```REGEXP_REPLACE ``` 使えないんですね。。

Comment: @Take MySQL のバージョン情報等は質問本文に直接追記しておくとよいと思います。